# Circular dependency of class delclarations

Tags: c++, friend, circular-dependency

I have two classes with separate headers: `class Renderer` and `class Texture`. The `Texture` instance is designed to manage some data that resides in the memory pool of a `Renderer`, and thus a `Texture` instance cannot exist independently of a `Renderer` instance. To get a handle to a `Texture` instance, one simply calls `Renderer::loadTexture` with the correct filename, and `Renderer` searches it's database for `Texture` objects with a matching filename and instantiates a new texture if no matches are found.

```
//renderer.h
#include "texture.h"
class renderer
{
public:
    Texture* loadTexture(std::string fileName);
private:
    std::map<std::string, Texture*> textureDb;
};

//texture.h
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(std::string imageFileName);
};
```

It occurred to me that it would be logical to make the constructors of `class Texture` private, and declare `Texture * Renderer::loadTexture(std::string filename)` as a friend of `class Renderer`:

```
//renderer.h
#include "texture.h"
class renderer
{
public:
    Texture* loadTexture(std::string fileName);
private:
    std::map<std::string, Texture*> textureDb;
};

//texture.h
class texture;
#include "renderer.h"
class Texture
{
private:
    Texture(std::string imageFileName);
    Texture(const Texture &);
    friend Texture* loadTexture(std::string);
};
```

However, this only compiles if texture.h is always included before including renderer.h, since `class Texture` requires `class Renderer` to be already defined. What would be the best way to prevent this? **Include guards are present on both files but are omitted here for brevity.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, from the code above, forward-declare where possible. This should help a bit.

```
// Renderer.h
class Texture;

class Renderer {
   ...
};

// Renderer.cpp
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "Texture.h"

...

// Texture.h
//class Renderer; // looks like this isn't needed

class Texture {
   ...
};

// Texture.cpp
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "Texture.h"

...
```

With the forward declarations, you should have enough to declare pointers to Texture in the Renderer class header. It looks like that's all you need at this point; push the rest to Renderer.cpp.

Next, avoid friends; however, it might be acceptable in this case.

Finally, circular dependencies are never a good thing. See if you can change your design a bit. See if you can introduce an interface or an abstract base class in order to break your circular dependency. It looks like Renderer shouldn't really need to depend on Texture at all.

Instead, consider rewriting Renderer to depend on some sort of ITexture interface, and then let Texture implement ITexture:

```
class ITexture
{
   // no data members
   // no method bodies
   // only pure virtual method declarations
};

class Renderer
{
public:
    ITexture* loadTexture(std::string fileName);
private:
    std::map<std::string, ITexture*> textureDb;
};

class Texture : public ITexture
{
   ...
};
```

Comment: "See if you can change your design a bit." I took the suggestion quite literally: Now class Texture is dependent on class Renderer, but not the other way around, and I wrote a resource management system that takes care of all ownership relations and data loading automatically.